# phusion passenger processes dying and new ones starting up mysteriously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

as you can see, passenger processes are dying and new ones booting up, even though we're not explicitly restarting passenger ourselves. we can't pinpoint what's causing this. what are some common places we should look to find out what's triggering these restarts?

the `passenger-status` commands were issued about 30 min apart. `passenger_pool_idle_time` is set to 0 in our conf file, which you can see here: https://gist.github.com/panabee/8ddf95a72d6a07e29c7f

we're on passenger 4.0.5, rails 3.2.12, and nginx 1.4.1.

```
[root@mongo ~]# passenger-status
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 20
Processes     : 3
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/p/p#default:
  App root: /home/p/p
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 17171   Sessions: 0       Processed: 536     Uptime: 27m 56s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 62M     Last used: 20s ago
  * PID: 18087   Sessions: 0       Processed: 363     Uptime: 17m 31s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 36M     Last used: 39s ago
  * PID: 19382   Sessions: 0       Processed: 51      Uptime: 2m 55s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 34M     Last used: 5s ago

[root@mongo ~]# passenger-status
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 20
Processes     : 2
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/p/p#default:
  App root: /home/p/p
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 25266   Sessions: 0       Processed: 73      Uptime: 2m 56s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 32M     Last used: 34s ago
  * PID: 25462   Sessions: 1       Processed: 18      Uptime: 51s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 28M     Last used: 0s ago

[root@mongo ~]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a bug in 4.0.5. 4.0.6 patches things. in the meantime, set the value to a very large number.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the web server error log. If the application dies you will probably see the reason in that log file.

Comment: thanks, @hongli. we love passenger, but ever since upgrading to 4, it doesn't seem like passenger_pool_idle_time is applying. did this change in 4.0.5? there are no errors in the log.

Comment: That is a bug in "pool_idle_time 0" support. It'll be fixed in 4.0.6.